# squid url_regex not matching characters

Tags: ubuntu, squid, squidguard

I have a url_regex acl:
^http(s)://bitbucket.org/example/*

However, it's matching the url:
http(s)://bitbucket.org/example_test/*

This seems to not consider the "/" at the end of ^http(s)://bitbucket.org/example/*

I'd like to match anything with subfolder matching example. Eg: bitbucket.org/example/case_1
bitbucket.org/example/case_2
But not, bitbucket.org/example_bad/case_3

It seems like a special blend of regex and its not considering the "/" –

Can anyone see what is wrong here ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with squid url_regex specifically, but normally the quantifier `*` would match *zero or more* of the previous atom (i.e. `/*` matches zero or more "/" characters. I suspect you want `/.*` or perhaps just `/`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd like to match anything with subfolder matching example. Eg: 
http://bitbucket.org/example/case_1
http://bitbucket.org/example/case_2
But not,
http://bitbucket.org/example_bad/case_3
It seems like a special blend of regex and its not considering the "/"

Comment: Yes that is the intention. I DO NOT want it to match example_test/ but it seems like it is. So I’m here scratching my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [steeldriver said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698000/squid-url-regex-not-matching-characters#comment1319013_698000), it’s matching
for the same reason `car*t` matches `cat`  — 
`*` means any number of the preceding character, ***including zero**.* 
`r*` matches the zero `r`’s between `a` and `t`,
and your `/*` is matching the zero slashes between `example` and `_test/*`.

Do you want to match `http(s)://bitbucket.org/example`
(without any subdirectory)? 
If not, it’s easy; just use

```
^http(s)://bitbucket.org/example/
```

or

```
^http(s)://bitbucket.org/example/.*$
```

If you ***do*** want to match `http(s)://bitbucket.org/example`,
it’s a bit trickier. 
You need `example` to be either at the end of the URL,
or followed by a slash. 
Some regex engines will let you say

```
^http(s)://bitbucket.org/example(/|$)
```

where the `|` inside `(`…`)` means “or”. 
For example, `grep -E` supports this. 
I don’t know whether this will work in Squid.

---

Does Squid let you specify multiple regexes? 
If it does, specify

```
^http(s)://bitbucket.org/example$
```

*and*

```
^http(s)://bitbucket.org/example/
```

Comment: Thanks ! That really explains it. I put in an extra / and it works now !